# upper-bounding $e$ by $\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+\delta}$ with a positive $\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, supremum-and-infimum

We know that

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x < e < \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1}$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{>0}$. My question is what is the infimum of $\delta\in\mathbb{R}^{>0}$ such that
$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+\delta}>e$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{>0}$?

Comment: "any" means in English both "some" **and** "every". Which one is the meaning in "for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^{>0}$"? In other words, are you searching for the infimum, given $x$, or the infimum over all $\delta$ **and** over all $x$?

Comment: @owl I think the post is clear: what is $\inf\{\delta>0\mid\forall x>0\quad (1 +1/x)^{x+\delta}>e\}$?

Comment: @AnneBauval No, it isn't. The word "any" has multiple (mathematically inequivalent) meanings. It can also mean $\inf\{\delta >0\mid (1+1/x)^{x+\delta}>e\}$

Comment: In this context it can't: look at the foreword "We know that...". In this foreword like in the question and in any ;-)  statement like "$P(x)$ for any $x$", I , like any ;-) mathematician, understand "any" as "every".

Comment: You are reading "any" as "every", but it also means "some". Common language sometimes is ambiguous like that. That is why it is good to avoid using "any" in mathematical writing. Both meanings fit that statement too.

Comment: @AnneBauval It is funny how people like to think that what they know and do, which is always quite limited within a sea of 8 billion people and 2K+ years of written history, is what everybody does. Just search the usage of the word "any". No, it isn't what every mathematician reads when they read "any".

Comment: @AnneBauval And this is a common language word. Wait until you see that actual mathematical concepts, like "function" or "irreducible space" also don't have unique definitions, but multiple, not always equivalent definitions.

Comment: For large $x$ you will find $\frac{1}{\log_e(1+\frac1x)} -x \approx \frac12$ and that $\delta=\frac12$ will answer your question

Comment: @owl Corrected, thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\inf\{\delta\in\Bbb R\mid\forall x>0\quad(1+1/x)^{x+\delta}>e\}=\frac12$$
because:
$$\begin{align}(\forall x>0\quad(1+1/x)^{x+\delta}>e)&\iff(\forall y>0\quad(\delta+1/y)\ln(1+y)>1)\\
&\iff(\forall t>1\quad\delta>\frac1{\ln t}-\frac1{t-1})\\
&\iff(\forall h>0\quad\delta>f(h):=\frac{e^h-1-h}{h(e^h-1)}),
\end{align}$$
$\lim_0f=\frac12,$
and
$$\forall h>0\quad e^h-1-h=\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{h^n}{n!}<\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{h^n}{2((n-1)!)}=\frac{h(e^h-1)}2.$$

Comment: Beautiful answer! Thanks a lot